# Comparing two Points

Tags: java, random, draw, point, graphic

I want to compare two points, if one point is in a specific area it should generate another, somehow my program doesn't do this...
This is just a part of it...

my imports:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
```

My method:

```
public void drawMiddle(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        targetPoint = new Point(1080/2, 768/2);
        g.fillOval((int) targetPoint.x-5, (int)targetPoint.y-5, radius*2, radius*2);

        if((faceCenter.x > targetPoint.x-5 && faceCenter.x < targetPoint.x +5)&&(faceCenter.y > targetPoint.y-5 && faceCenter.y < targetPoint.y +5)){
            System.out.println("MATCH");
            // targetPoint random generieren
            targetPoint = new Point(Math.random()*1000+100, Math.random()*700+100);
            repaint();
        }


    }
```

If you need any other informations pls let me know :)

EDIT: The program comes into the if clause now, and writes MATCH, but it doesn't generate a new Point, anything false with repaint()?

Comment: Please show a *short but complete* program demonstrating the problem. Your current code is incomplete, contains irrelevant parts such as drawing, and doesn't include any samples which go wrong.

Comment: Okay, you created new `Point`, so shouldn't you do something with it? Paint it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine `Area` is something, which has its x,y coordinates and its x,y size. `Point` has its x,y coords. Then you can define a function like this

```
public boolean isPointInArea(Area a, Point p){
    return (area.x <= myPoint.x && myPoint.x <= area.x + area.size_x &&
            area.y <= myPoint.y && myPoint.y <= area.y + area.size_y);
}

/* ... */

if (isPointInArea(area, point))
    spawnNewPoint();
```

It's pretty simple way of checking whether certain point belogs to certain area.